# monetdb incorrect data insert/update

Tags: node.js, monetdb

I am using MonetDB to store and analyze email campaign data. I have one table with about 6 million data. Table has around 30 columns. 
When I select some of the data, I realise that data are not correctly inserted/updated. 
When I fire `"select contactId, email, templateId from statistics.marketing_sent where contactid = '974c47e2'"`, I expect the following result.

```
+-----------+---------------------+------------+
| contactid | email               | templateid |
+===========+=====================+============+
| 974c47e2  | tom@frerickslaw.com |         34 |
+-----------+---------------------+------------+
```

But I receive the following result and found email is wrong.

```
+-----------+-----------------+------------+
| contactid | email           | templateid |
+===========+=================+============+
| 974c47e2  | frank@fsfco.com |         34 |
+-----------+-----------------+------------+
```

I double check my nodejs program that insert and update the data. I do not find any issue. 
After that what I do is, I have created new empty table and start inserting/updating on that table. New table has 500k~ data and all ware correct. But I need all those data in main table. 
So, I fire `"insert into statistics.marketing_sent select * from statistics.marketing_sent_2"`. And I again found that data are incorrect.

Is there any one who face this kind of issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is weird.  Are you absolutely sure that "frank@fsfco.com" is the email associated with the contactid "974c47e2"?  Can you please double check the original data that you have inserted into MonetDB (i.e. not selected from "statistics.marketing_sent_2", because how do you know the data in this table are correct?)

Having said that, your problem looks like wrong string pointers have been involved in processing your query.  I have seen earlier this year that in some extremely specific cases, the wrong value is used as the OFFSET to point to the string in the string HEAP.  That problem was fixed several release ago.

With which MonetDB version were your data inserted?  Is this a reproducible problem with the latest release of MonetDB (i.e. Jul2017-SP1)?  If the problem persists, can you please submit a bug report (https://www.monetdb.org/bugzilla/) with the table schema, sample data and script/queries to reproduce your problem?  Thanks

Jennie

Comment: I am using Dec2016-SP3 version. I haven't tried latest version yet. I will try with latest version and see this problem persists or not.